# deploy multiple enpoint api google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have 2 json files, I want to deploy on GCloud

With this command:

```
 gcloud endpoints services deploy first_file.json
 gcloud endpoints services deploy second_file.json
```

But after second file deploys the first one is removed.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

If both files are for the same service you should check [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/deploy-endpoints-config#deploying_the_configuration_files) documentation on how to deploy configuration files. You might be also having some issues with naming, as described in the description of the `gcloud endpoints services deploy` [page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/endpoints/services/deploy).

Besides that, [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine-standard) you'll find tutorials on how to configure Endpoints on App Engine Standard.

If this is not the case, please add more information to the question, such as what is your use case and some code if possible.